# IBM Social Business Toolkit getContacts API Fails With 403 Forbidden

Tags: ibm-sbt

I used to be able to use the IBM SBT getContacts API from either a perl script (with authentication provided in the request) or an internet browser (authentication popup would appear) and it would return the data in JSON format as documented on the IBM Connections Developers API reference page:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Contacts_getContacts_API&content=apicontent&sa=true

Recently, however, the API call has been returning a 403 forbidden status. If I sign in to the IBM Connections Cloud before trying to use the API via a browser, it is converted to:

https://apps.na.collabserv.com/mycontacts/home.html

Does anyone know what I need to do to get the API to work again?

Thanks.

Comment: please use this api... http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=SmartCloud_Contacts&content=apicontent

Comment: I am also following up on the API status for use.

Comment: Thanks Paul. This API does return data for me versus returning an error when I use it in a browser. I still need to make sure it will work from my Perl script but am hopeful.

Comment: This API worked successfully from my Perl script. Thanks for the help, Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best API to use are 
https://apps.na.collabserv.com/lotuslive-shindig-server/social/rest/people/@me/@all?filterBy=type&filterOp=equals&filterValue=contacts&format=json

You'll get a list of the following entries back...

```
{
           "photos":
           [
           ],
           "telephone": "",
           "profileUrl": "",
           "mobilephone": "",
           "orgs":
           [
               {
                   "value": "CONTACTS",
                   "type": "Source"
               },
               {
                   "value": "Mentorship Expressway",
                   "type": "Org"
               }
           ],
           "website": "",
           "id": "na.collabserv.com:contact:160000909070",
           "fax": "",
           "connectedToId": 201238541234,
           "addresses":
           [
           ],
           "emailAddress": "asdfasdf@us.ibm.com",
           "websites":
           [
           ],
           "objectId": 160000909070,
           "type": "FRIEND",
           "jobtitle": "",
           "updated": "2014-07-01T16:44:21.000Z",
           "ims":
           [
           ],
           "emails":
           [
               {
                   "value": "CONTACTS",
                   "type": "Source"
               },
               {
                   "title": "Primary Email",
                   "email": "asdfasdf@us.ibm.com"
               }
           ],
           "org":
           {
               "name": "Mentorship Expressway"
           },
           "displayName": "asdfasdf",
           "address": "",
           "companyId": 22285,
           "phoneNumbers":
           [
               {
                   "value": "CONTACTS",
                   "type": "Source"
               },
               {
                   "title": "MOBILE",
                   "phone": "+ asdfasdf"
               }
           ]
       }
```

Comment: This looks like it should do the trick, thanks. Note that there is a minor typo in the URL that needs to be corrected: colalbserv vs collabserv.

Comment: just accepted the change.  I modified the URL for a production environment.